# Additional explanation needed for the solution to a spesific sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, contest-math

[image]

Some of my attempts include trying to use the the term formula for geometric sequences and some other manipulations in hope of getting a more clearer, workable expression, though without success. The solution's first line is especially unclear to me. Some clarification?

Comment: $x+1/x$ has a minimum in 2, so you can find a real $x$ such that $2c=x+1/x$

Comment: The given solution has an error: $a_n=x^{+(n-1)}+x^{-(n-1)}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$.